# need to insert data in child along with identity Key from master

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below 3 tables `#tblData`, `#tblMaster` and `#tblChild`, where I need to split `#tblData` into 2 other tables `#tblMaster` and `#tblChild`.

In `#tblChild` table, I need identity Key from `#tblMaster` along with other data from `#tblData` table.

```
Create Table #tblData (UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
insert into #tblData values ('uq1', getdate(), 'abc'), ('uq2', getdate(), 'xyz')
--select * from #tblData
create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(1,1), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
create Table #tblChild (ChildId INT IDENTITY(10,10), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME)

drop table #tblChild
drop table #tblMaster
drop table #tblData
```

Through below query I am able to insert data into "#tblMaster" and able to store Identity into a table variable "@OutputTbl".

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (MasterId INT)
INSERT INTO #tblMaster(DateTimeNow, UpdateBy)
 OUTPUT INSERTED.MasterId INTO @OutputTbl(MasterId)
SELECT DateTimeNow, UpdateBy FROM #tblData
```

How to get other values from `#tblData` into table variable `@OutputTb` so that I can insert `@OutputTb` into `#tblChild` table **OR** is there any other way to do that?

Comment: How are the three tables related to each other i.e. what decides whether 'uq1' should go to first row or second row in child table?

Comment: @shree, very valid point. currently this is sequential. Assume we have one    Identity column in table "#tblData"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you are on SQL Server 2008 or above you could use [OUTPUT and MERGE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx).

I've used the above approach and found it to work well.

Comment: i m using SQL 2008